# useState variable not updating consistently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Background:

I'm making a guessing game app where an image is displayed, and the user will guess the name of the character in a text box, on a predetermined number of rounds with a time limit. The input is checked every time a character is entered. The game will go to the next round either from having a correct answer, or the time running out.

Problem:

The game randomly picks a character to be guessed. That name is used to be inserted in a url to display the image. The name is assigned to a variable using `useState()`. The problem is that the variable is not being updated when the timer runs out, but somehow updated when the answer is correct.

What I tried:

I used another variable that is traditionally declared, and it somehow has the opposite behavior than the original one, so I just pass a boolean to assign either variable to a final variable.

```js
function App() {
  const input = React.useRef()
  const loopProgress = React.useRef() // for animating progress bar
  const deadline = React.useRef() // deadline for each round
  
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(0) // progress bar
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('')
  const [rounds, setRounds] = React.useState(0)
  const imageNames = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5']
  const [pickedIndices, setPickedIndices] = React.useState([])
  let name2 = ''
  
  function checkAnswer() {
    // just assuming the same answer to all characters
    if (input.current.value === 'foo') {
      // correct answer
      input.current.value = ''
      clearInterval(loopProgress.current)
      clearTimeout(deadline.current)
      main(true)
    }
  }
  
  function main(isCorrect) {
    console.log(name, name2)
    // place to insert name in a url to display the image
    // my ugly solution
    const finalName = isCorrect ? name : name2
    newGame() // another round
  }
  
  function getName() {
    // pick random answer
    let newShipPicked = false, randShipIndex
    while (!newShipPicked) {
      randShipIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageNames.length)
      if (!pickedIndices.includes(randShipIndex)) {
        setPickedIndices((pickedIndices) => {
          pickedIndices.push(randShipIndex)
          return pickedIndices
        })
        newShipPicked = true
      }
    }
    name2 = imageNames[randShipIndex]
    setName(imageNames[randShipIndex])
  }
  
  function newGame() {
    setProgress(0)
    setRounds((rounds) => rounds + 1)
    getName()
    
    const roundDuration = 5000
    const interval = 10
    const totalSteps = roundDuration / interval

    loopProgress.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (progress < 100) {
        setProgress((prevProgress) => prevProgress + (100 / totalSteps))
      }
    }, interval)

    deadline.current = setTimeout(() => {
      // not answered
      clearInterval(loopProgress.current)
      main(false)
    }, roundDuration)
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // stop game
    if (rounds === 6) {
      clearInterval(loopProgress.current)
      clearTimeout(deadline.current)
    }
  }, [rounds])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{rounds !== 6 ? Math.round(progress) : 'done'}</p>
      <input type='text' ref={input} onInput={checkAnswer}></input>
      <button onClick={newGame}>Start</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/g8znq0cm/3/)

Focusing on the console.log's, here's an example list of logs basing on whether the answer is correct or the time runs out.

Table shows ordered events. Output is numbered just for clarity and example but in actuality it's random. Code implies 5 rounds but assume this one has more rounds for more examples.

| round outcome | name (useState var) | name2 (trad. var) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| time runs out | (empty) | img1 |
| time runs out | (empty) | img2 |
| time runs out | (empty) | img3 |
| correct answer | img4 | (empty) |
| correct answer | img5 | (empty) |
| time runs out | img5 | img6 |
| time runs out | img5 | img7 |
| time runs out | img5 | img8 |
| correct answer | img9 | (empty) |
| correct answer | img10 | (empty) |

When the timer runs out, `name` has the same or "outdated" variable, while `name2` has the expected output.

When the answer is correct, `name` has the expected output, while `name2` is empty.

I tried to see what caused this error, I tried backtracking to see which code affects the output of the mentioned variables, but to no avail. For me I just expect the `useState` variable to behave normally whatever the outcome.

What I want is to use just one variable for this, where it has the expected output regardless of the round outcome.

Comment: Stale closure probably. When you are creating the timeout the name still has the old value.